# Редактирование ячеек в таблице в Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Я хочу сделать так чтобы данные в таблице менялись по релевантности из `True` (когда свободно) в `False` (когда занято) у меня соединение один ко многим (`ForeignKey`) все это надо сделать в `Django 4.0`

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Rooms(models.Model):
    room_num = models.IntegerField()
    room_bool = models.BooleanField(default=True)  #это надо соединить с моделью Registration
    category = models.CharField(max_length=150)


class Registration(models.Model):
    rooms = models.ForeignKey(Rooms, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pasport_serial_num = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    img = models.FileField()
    visit_date = models.DateTimeField()
    leave_date = models.DateTimeField()
    guest_count = models.IntegerField()
    rooms_bool = models.BooleanField(default=True) #это надо соединить с главной моделью (Rooms)
```

Comment: это наверно стоит в логике делать, когда происходит регистрация находить нужную комнату и менять ее статус и наоборот, когда срок регистрации закончился снимать этот флаг, еще как вариант django-signals использовать на  save, update но тут стоит ожидать подвоха в конечном итоге

Comment: мой проект не ограничен одним лишь сайтом там логика такова что если пришел гость снял номер через сайт то, уже нельзя будет открыть комнату не через ресепшн не через бота. В боте это реализовать оч просто но вот в django не знаю как отредачить все bool

Comment: бот и сайт работают на одной базе? повторюсь, почему нельзя в момент "снятия номера" переводить статус `room_bool` в true/false, либо я не понимаю что вы хотите сделать, а с учетом что больше нет комментаторов, то не я один

Comment: да на одной бд мы и так подтверждаем на true false просто хотелось на автомате везде